# Display div when certain sections are in view with jquery / javascript and scrollify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-scrollify

I have a website page with four sections which are `100%` width and height, and I'm using scrollify so the browser window always snaps to a section.

1. I have a fixed header that I want to display only while either of the middle two sections (`#b` and `#c`) are in view.
2. I'd like for this header to fade in and fade out. It should be gone by the time section #a or #d is snapped to.

I'm a novice at writing Javascript, so a fully functional solution which works with my code snippet would be much appreciated.

```js
$(function() {
  $.scrollify({
    section: "section",
    easing: "swing",
    scrollSpeed: 500,
    offset: 0,
    scrollbars: true,
    before: function() {},
    after: function() {},
    afterResize: function() {}
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#a {
  background: #aaa;
}
#b {
  background: #bbb;
}
#c {
  background: #ccc;
}
#d {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollify/0.1.11/jquery.scrollify.min.js">
</script>
<div id="header">
</div>
<section id="a">
</section>
<section id="b">
</section>
<section id="c">
</section>
<section id="d">
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `before` event of scrollify. In this event you should get a current slide with the method `$.scrollify.current();` You can find all available methods [here](http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#methods-continued)! And depending on your slide you can hide or show your header. 
Simply use `if (){} else {}` construction.
Example:

```
if (currentSlide != 1 || currentSlide != 3) {
 header.show();
} else {
 header.hide();
}
```

or just add some class to header

```
if (currentSlide != 1 || currentSlide != 3) {
 header.addClass('is-shown');
} else {
 header.removeClass('is-shown');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2Lo92L6s/

Comment: Could you show me exactly how to implement this in my code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by jquery.you have to capture section load event and check the section id.if its is #a or #d you have to use:

```
if(id == "a" or id == "b")
{
   $("#header").hide();
}
else{
   $("#header").show();
}
```

Comment: Could you show me exactly how to implement this in my code snippet?